# Is there a standard way of referring to electronic files?

Tags: computing, style-manuals, convention

If I'm writing about a specific computer file - let's say a file which looks, in some view, to be named ExampleFile.pdf (which is already problematic, since what you see might depend on the details of the computer), and I want to say "You can find this information in ExampleFile.pdf". Should I drop the extension? Should I italic it, or add quotes? Should I say something like "...when viewed in Windows 10 version 20H2 is called...."?

I suppose there might be even be "good practice" for not referring to the file by name at all.

Are there any standards out there for this situation?

EDIT: To be clear, I'm thinking about a formal document, not something like an email or blog post. If I was writing a formal letter, or perhaps a peer-reviewed article.

Comment: Don't all pdf files look the same, as that ability is their portability? Also, go ahead and refer to the file by name. If attaching one file, no need to mention pdf, but there's no harm.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: Maybe I should had picked a different file type, that's true, but there are also encoding issues. Or, some computer systems can't deal well with spaces in file names.

Comment: If there are encoding issues, maybe this does not belong here?

Comment: @Cascabel That's one possible perspective - that in formal language one should never refer to a digital file by name (maybe "the file that contains the information...." would be appropriate) - without giving exactly how to view the name of the file (OS, hardware, encoding, etc). The second case is totally impractical, but possibly an answer. Any sources for that opinion?

Comment: if the file only exists on one computer then it will be viewed on that computer using the filesystem and viewing software on that computer.  If the file is being distributed, then it should be in a portable document format at that point it should only be necessary to add “which may be viewed with XYZ application version v.x or later”

Comment: Why should an electronic file be different from paper? We've had them for decades now. "I'll send you a copy of my latest book." "I'll send you my *Tale of Two Cities*." "Oh, by the way, can you read Sans Serif?" In a book repository, it might be filed by a reference number (say its ISBN, later).

Comment: I'm not sure there's an actual standard, though specific organisations may have a house style for this. In ours, it would be to refer to the document's title, file type _and_ the file name to account for the different ways it might be identified: e.g. "You can find this information in the _Really Important Document_ PDF (Really-Important-2020-v2.pdf)". Stating the document's real title helps anyone who has a printed copy or who has renamed the file; stating the file type, rather than relying on the extension being visible, will help readers whose system masks the file extension by default.

Comment: @NickK Good answer, worth posting as such.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - If all pdf files looked the same there wouldn't be millions (or maybe billions) of them.

Comment: @HotLicks Mea culpa for my vague language.

Comment: @WeatherVane an electronic file differs from a paper file in several ways. Materially, it's pretty clear how one interacts with a paper file - it's paper, we look at it, and we read it (if we can understand the language). An electronic file is a bunch of bits, and requires an interpreter (Notepad, Emacs, Word, etc) which runs in an OS (Windows, OSX, Linux, etc) that runs on a set of hardware (CPU, HD, etc). There's a lot between the reader and the actual material content.

Comment: @NickK I like this, because it at least provides a method to determine if you're looking at the right file - you can confirm both the name and the extension. But you emphasize part of the origin of my question in stating what you would do in your own organization (in mine, I think I would follow the same approach). Are there no MLA/APA-style guidelines for this?

Comment: @cduston that might be a matter of opinion. If you look at a book from too far away, or from too close, it can't be read. Too close, and all you see is fibres smudged by ink, not so very different from a file of bits. A book only makes sense when looked at in the right way (and for most people, the right way up). Some people might not be able to read a book at all, without special tools, and as you say, it might need to be translated.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't agree, but I do see the perspective you're bringing. We all know already what is required to read a book - pick it up, open it, can you read it? Electronic files typically contain information about how to "read" the file (in a header, or something), but you might need additional information to even know where to find that. To me there is no equivalent to the random rules you can put on electronic files in the real, physical world. And this is before we even consider the fidelity of the information transmitted.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the extent to which you and the other person know about the file already. However, no one goes wrong by being specific, so just cite the full file with the extension.